# How can I make list of R dataframe columns conditional on value of another column

Tags: r, dataframe

Lets say that I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(VAR1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), VAR2 = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"))
```

and I want to make a list of VAR1 values grouped by each VAR2 level:

```
myList <- list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6))
```

I can use:

```
myList <- list(df[df$VAR2 == "A", ]$VAR1, df[df$VAR2 == "B", ]$VAR1)
```

Ideally though I'd like to use more straightforward solution w/o hardcoding because I have larger data with many levels in the factor variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `split`

```
split(df$VAR1, df$VAR2)
```